# where is 'secure' tag in Magento cookie on SSL secure site?

Tags: php, magento, cookies, http-headers

Our site is SSL secured site, and Magento 'secure' and 'unsecure' URL variables both point at https:// URL.  However PCI audit indicated that cookies are unsecure.  They want to see the 'secure' keyword when cookies are created via Set-Cookie in page header.

I see Magento uses this function in \shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cookie.php

```
if (is_null($secure)) {
            $secure = $this->isSecure();
        }
        if (is_null($httponly)) {
            $httponly = $this->getHttponly();
        }

        setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
```

but I am not sure where value is isSecure() is coming from and why does not contain text 'secure'?

SetCookie in page header:

```
frontend=sj4j9kltv7nc00gk8s0i81koi3; expires=Thu, 06-Nov-2014 23:39:11 GMT; 
path=/; domain=www.mydomaine.com; HttpOnly"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento set secure cookies for admin only, try to install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/secure-frontend-cookie.html module, it should help :)

If it does not help help just override `isSecure` from `Mage_Core_Model_Cookie` model, method:

```
public function isSecure()
{ 
    return $this->_getRequest()->isSecure(); 
}
```

Comment: If anyone is still looking for this functionality, it is available in this repo: https://github.com/lukanetconsult/mage-secure-cookie

Comment: Fix for m2? @kuba_ceg

Comment: Its not working, cookies are still without httponly & unsecure tag